# JSF Primefaces required value issue with multiple commandbutton

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

My problem is I have more than one `Primefaces`'s  `commandButton` in an xhtml page.My required messages and validators work for each of them. This is not what I desire. I want that the required messages and validators should work only when I clicked the commandbutton with the id is "`sendform`"

```
<p:growl id="growl" life="6000" />

    <p:inputText id="fullName" 
                 value="#{messageBean.fullName}" 
                 required="true" 
                 requiredMessage="You need to enter your full name to apply this form." 
                 styleClass="contacttext"/>

    <p:inputText id="email" 
                 value="#{messageBean.email}" 
                 required="true" 
                 requiredMessage="You need to enter your email to apply this form." 
                 validatorMessage="Invalid e-mail format">
                        <f:validateRegex pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" /> 
    </p:inputText>

    <p:commandButton id="sendform" 
                     value="#{msg['sendUs']}" 
                     actionListener="#{messageBean.sendMessage}" 
                     update="growl fullName email textarea" 
                     styleClass="sendus"/>

<p:commandButton id ="otherStuff" 
                 value="otherStuff" 
                 actionlistener="#{someBean.someWork}" />
<p:commandButton id ="anotherStuff" 
                 value="anotherStuff" 
                 actionlistener="#{anotherBean.anotherWork}" />
```

How can I fix it up to run required messages only this commandbutton?

```
 <p:commandButton id="sendform" 
                  value="#{msg['sendUs']}" 
                  actionListener="#{messageBean.sendMessage}" 
                  update="growl fullName email textarea" 
                  styleClass="sendus"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip the validation for all fields whenever the button in question is been pressed.

You can achieve as below code.

```
<p:inputText id="fullName" required="#{not empty param[sendForm.clientId]}" />

<p:inputText id="email" required="#{not empty param[sendForm.clientId]}" />

<p:commandButton id="sendform" 
                 binding="#{sendForm}"
                 value="#{msg['sendUs']}" 
                 actionListener="#{messageBean.sendMessage}" 
                 update="growl fullName email textarea" 
                 styleClass="sendus"/>
<p:commandButton id ="otherStuff" 
             value="otherStuff" 
             actionlistener="#{someBean.someWork}" />
<p:commandButton id ="anotherStuff" 
             value="anotherStuff" 
             actionlistener="#{anotherBean.anotherWork}" />
```

You can see another example from legendary [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) at [How to let validation depend on the pressed button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370675/how-to-let-validation-depend-on-the-pressed-button)

Answer (score 1):

Use `process` attribute on each command button, to specify which components should be processed when the button is clicked. Some basic setup, based on your sample code, would be to leave the `sendform` button as it is, and to add `process="@this"` to `otherStuff` and `anotherStuff` buttons. Just add component ids to `process` attribute if anything else should be processed.

Comment: thank you @Predrag Maric, I learn process for primefaces and execute for jsf