# Submit empty value to bean anyway on input with required="true"

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, required

I've the below input with `required="true"`:

```
<p:inputText value="#{bean.value}" required="true">
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.change()}" />
</p:inputText>
```

When user changes the value, the listener is fired and I can access the changed value. When user empties the field, the listener is not fired and the empty value is not updating in my bean. I gather that this is caused by `requried="true"`. I would like to update my bean with empty value and fire the listener anyway when the user empties the field. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is purposeless. Any action(Listener) is not invoked, when any conversion/validation violation occurs.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use expression language (EL) in the `required` attribute too. You can then just check if the main submit button of the form has been pressed. Imagine that your form has a "Save" button like below,

```
<p:inputText ... required="true">
    <p:ajax ... />
</p:inputText>
...
<p:commandButton ... action="#{bean.save}" />
```

Then you can let the `required` attribute evaluate `true` only if the button is invoked. You can achieve that by referencing the component via `binding` and checking if its client ID is present in the HTTP request parameter map:

```
<p:inputText ... required="#{not empty param[save.clientId]}">
    <p:ajax ... />
</p:inputText>
...
<p:commandButton binding="#{save}" ... action="#{bean.save}" />
```

Note that `#{save}` is as-is and may absolutely not be bound to a backing bean, and that the variable name must be unique in the current view and EL scope.

#### See also:

- [How to let validation depend on the pressed button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370675/how-to-let-validation-depend-on-the-pressed-button)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and editing the question, i have did the same thing what you said. even though the ajax listner is not calling when i am trying to make the field empty , plz help me in this.

Comment: Works fine for me. Which JSF impl/version are you using?

Comment: JSF version is 2.1 and prime faces 5.0

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370675/how-to-let-validation-depend-on-the-pressed-button

Comment: @Kukeltje: I considered that, but as the question is asked from a different perspective I imagined that no one could understand how the answer is applicable.

Comment: lucky me... Now I'm sure I'm somebody and not no one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that if the user clears the required input field then 'required' validator throws an exception and bean setter will not be called. When the form is reloaded then cleared value will show up again from the bean. Here is my workaround:

```
public String getSomething() {
    return isFormValueEmpty("form:something") ? null : this.something;
}

private Boolean isFormValueEmpty(String formFieldName) {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    String formValue = ec.getRequestParameterMap().get(formFieldName);
    logger.debug("Check if form value is empty: [{}] [{}]", formFieldName, formValue);
    return StringUtils.isEmpty(formValue);
}
```