# What is the correct way to use RequestScoped Bean and rendered attribute?

Tags: jsf, rendered-attribute, requestscope

does anybody know how to use RequestScoped bean together with rendered attribute in jsf? The rendered attribute is evaluated before applyValues phase and therefore is not correctly evaluated. I don't want to preserve any state. The example could be an outputPanel with a datatable and a button. The datatable gets a list of values. The wrapping outputPanel has the rendered attribute like:

```
<p:outputPanel rendered="#{not empty requestScopedBean.dataList}">
    <p:datatable value="#{requestScopedBean.dataList}">
        ...
    </p:datatable>

    <p:commandButton action="#{requestScopedBean.someAction}" />
</p:outputPanel>
```

After loading the page and clicking on the button, nothing happens, because the view is restored and expressions are evaluated - the bean does have an empty datalist and therefore the panel should not be rendered. This causes that the action method is not even called - because the button doesn't exist.

Comment: This is not the first time that one has to remove [java] tag from your [jsf] question. Can you please take that as a hint to not add the [java] tag to a future [jsf] question anymore? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not interested in having a filled data table at that moment, just add an extra check in `rendered` attribute if the command button of interest has been invoked. You can do that by checking the presence of button's client ID in request parameter map.

```
<p:outputPanel rendered="#{not empty requestScopedBean.dataList or not empty param[someButton.clientId]}">
    ...

    <p:commandButton binding="#{someButton}" ... />
</p:outputPanel>
```

#### See also:

- [How to let validation depend on the pressed button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370675/how-to-let-validation-depend-on-the-pressed-button)

Comment: Yes. This does the trick. But on a page with more controls this would get pretty huge and unreadeable, not to mention hard to maintain. Isn't it then a rule that properties of RequestScoped beans should never be used in rendered, disabled, etc... attributes?

Comment: Nope, it's part of JSF's safeguard against tampered requests. The technical correct solution is using a view scoped bean instead of a request scoped bean.

Comment: What is then the correct way to have a search page with search results that I don't want to ever expire? I mean, to have search results displayed somewhere and update a block of page on click on one of the results. I don't need to preserve the list of results anywhere on server, they are displayed just once. And on click on one of them I would like to load additional info and show in a different block of a page.

Comment: Don't use a stateful view then. Conditionally show/hide at client level. E.g. `<div class="#{empty bean.list ? 'hidden' : ''}">` with `.hidden { display: none; }`.