# Submitting form without require validations with commandButton

Tags: forms, validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a big form on a JSF page using lots of components (PrimeFaces).
They are using different validations (like min size/max size, patterns or even custom), but some of them are marked as required using `required="true"` or the `requiredValidator`.

I want to add a new commandButton to submit the form and do all the validation except the different require validations so that a missing input is ok but not a wrong format.

As for now, I don't see how this could be handled in JSF and I hope someone could give me a hint or something to find a way to implement this.

Comment: Does any of the links here help: https://www.google.nl/search?q=conditionally+required+validator+jsf

Comment: What is `requiredValidator` ? Do you mean 'requiredMessage'?

Comment: No can't do either skip the whole validation phase using ``immediate=true`` or add a listener to skip required validation before validation phase starts.

Comment: Thanks, after reading mor on these, I realized I can use something like this: required="#{not empty param[componentName.clientId]}". But this is a problem if the InputComponent is included from a different xhtml to different views. In some of them the "componentName" (commandButton) may not exist so it will fail. what is a way to avoid this? Hard coding this seems to me not good ...

Answer (score 0):

To skip required validation completely you can set `immediate=true` on the button. If you want some of the element gets validated but some skipped, then use conditional 'required' as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370675/how-to-let-validation-depend-on-the-pressed-button).